ksql: Gaps when using a windowed table
I have three different event types (with different fields) which are linked by a common ID named main__id. I throw them into one stream and initialize initial_timestamp with NULL:
CREATE STREAM IF NOT EXISTS s_raw_events_aggregated (
  main__id VARCHAR KEY,
  timestamp BIGINT,
  initial_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
  loop_counter INT,
  `@timestamp` VARCHAR,
  hash_value VARCHAR, 
  user_agent__original VARCHAR,
  event__duration VARCHAR,
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC='s_raw_events_aggregated',
  PARTITIONS=3,
  REPLICAS=2,
  VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
  RETENTION_MS=3600000
);


INSERT INTO s_raw_events_aggregated
SELECT
  main__id,
  timestamp,
  CAST(null AS TIMESTAMP) AS initial_timestamp,
  CAST(0 AS INT) AS loop_counter,
  `@timestamp`,
  CAST(null AS VARCHAR) AS hash_value, 
  CAST(null AS VARCHAR) AS user_agent__original,
  event__duration
FROM s_session_end
PARTITION BY main__id;


INSERT INTO s_raw_events_aggregated
SELECT
  main__id,
  timestamp,
  CAST(null AS TIMESTAMP) AS initial_timestamp,
  CAST(0 AS INT) AS loop_counter,
  `@timestamp`,
  hash_value, 
  CAST(null AS VARCHAR) AS user_agent__original,
  CAST(null AS VARCHAR) AS event__duration
FROM s_hash_info
PARTITION BY main__id;


INSERT INTO s_raw_events_aggregated
SELECT
  main__id,
  timestamp,
  CAST(null AS TIMESTAMP) AS initial_timestamp,
  CAST(0 AS INT) AS loop_counter,
  `@timestamp`,
  CAST(null AS VARCHAR) AS hash_value, 
  user_agent__original,
  CAST(null AS VARCHAR) AS event__duration
FROM s_browser_info
PARTITION BY main__id;

Next, I want to collect the three events per main__id into one by putting them into a windowed table. If the row is not completed, my idea was to just reintroduce it to the stream before the table up to 12h long before I give up on them.
I don't know whether this is a valid concept in kSQL since there are no messages in the final stream with `LOOP_COUNTER`>0, although I verified that messages are indeed looped with counter value 1. Please share your knowledge.
(I tried it with a non-windowed table with even 24h retention and it worked fine.)
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t_combined
AS SELECT
  main__id AS agg_key,
  AS_VALUE(main__id) AS main__id,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(timestamp) AS timestamp,
  WINDOWSTART AS WINDOW_START,
  MAX(loop_counter) AS loop_counter,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(initial_timestamp) AS initial_timestamp,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(`@timestamp`) AS `@timestamp`,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(hash_value) AS hash_value,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(user_agent__original) AS user_agent__original,
  LATEST_BY_OFFSET(event__duration) AS event__duration
FROM s_raw_events_aggregated
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 20 MINUTES, GRACE PERIOD 0 MINUTES)
GROUP BY main__id
EMIT FINAL;


CREATE STREAM IF NOT EXISTS s_combined (
  main__id VARCHAR,
  timestamp BIGINT,
  WINDOW_START TIMESTAMP,
  initial_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
  loop_counter INT,
  `@timestamp` VARCHAR,
  hash_value VARCHAR,
  user_agent__original VARCHAR,
  event__duration VARCHAR
) WITH (
  KAFKA_TOPIC='T_COMBINED',
  PARTITIONS=3,
  REPLICAS=2,
  VALUE_FORMAT='JSON',
  RETENTION_MS=3600000
);

Looping it if incomplete or collecting it otherwise:
INSERT INTO s_raw_events_aggregated
SELECT
  main__id,
  timestamp,
  ARRAY_MIN(ARRAY[initial_timestamp, WINDOW_START]) AS initial_timestamp,
  loop_counter + 1 AS loop_counter,
  `@timestamp`,
  hash_value, 
  user_agent__original,
  event__duration
FROM s_combined
WHERE (event__duration IS NULL OR hash_value IS NULL OR user_agent__original IS NULL) AND (TIMESTAMPADD(HOURS, 12, ARRAY_MIN(ARRAY[initial_timestamp, WINDOW_START]))>WINDOW_START)
PARTITION BY main__id;

CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM s_output WITH (PARTITIONS=3, REPLICAS=2, VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', RETENTION_MS=600000) AS
SELECT 
  STRUCT(`id`:=main__id) AS `FLOW`,
  `@timestamp`,
  loop_counter,
  STRUCT(`value`:=hash_value) AS `has`,
  STRUCT(`original`:=user_agent__original) AS `user_agent`,
  STRUCT(`duration`:=event__duration) AS `event`
FROM s_combined
WHERE event__duration IS NOT NULL AND hash_value IS NOT NULL AND user_agent__original IS NOT NULL
EMIT CHANGES;

Even without the looping, the data I get compared to the input data and my other try without a window has gaps of two minutes between the windows. I tried with windows of 10 and 20 minutes and there will be gaps between the windows. Do you have any idea what's the problem?
It appears that the window has a certain start up time. I thought, Kafka's main advantage is the exactly-once capability.
Thank you!
I'm using 7.6.0 version of ksqldb in Kubernetes with a single server pod.
